# How to charge a battery pack through BMS using same pins as for the BMS output

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, bms

I'm bulding a 18650 4S pack for a speaker and I'm using a BMS capable of balancing and protecting the batteries like on the picture below. The manufacturer advertizes you can both charge and discharge using the same pair of pins (+-). How would this work and is it safe to charge the pack like this?

[image]

My plan was to be capable of charging it via a USB C conector and boosting the voltage to 16.8V. If my thinking is correct, connecting two pairs of wires to the same pins (one as an output for charging the speaker and the other as charging input from the boost converter), the BMS pins would output some voltage from the batteries that would 'push back' against the charging voltage via boost converter. I don't know the right names for this, but wouldn't the power supply essentialy charge using it's 'inertia'? Like to push stronger that what the batteries provide?

If this is somewhat correct then how can I safely charge the pack? Or would a better BMS like this with dedicated pins for charge and load solve the issue? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: For a start, you need a proper charging circuit - not just a boost converter.

Comment: @Finbarr Yes, that's what I'm asking. What do I need to add to be able to charge throught the first BMS or the second one? Both are capable of protecting and balancing the batteries.

Comment: A BMS is not a charger. You need a proper charging circuit that carries out two step CC/CV charging and shuts off when the battery is full, otherwise you may overcharge them and that can be extremely catastrophic.

Comment: @Dan You need, as said already, a charger. A lithium battery charger, capable of charging a 4S pack. How to connect the charger via some BMS to batteries is dependent on the BMS.

Comment: @Justme So a charger to power socket for charging 4S 16.8V will do? My problem is that I would like to be able to plug that speaker to any USB laying around without the need to carry a speacial charger. I'd like to build in the system what the charger does basically.

Comment: @Dan Yes, you need a lithium charger that charges the lithium batteries as they are supposed to. It does not matter from where the charger is supplied with power, mains, USB, or whatever. You can build one in into your speaker, you don't need to have a separate special charger. Just look at your mobile phone. It has USB input and it has a charger for the battery.

Comment: The BMS is advertized as capable of both safely discharging and charging the batteries, so it should cut off the voltage when the battery is full. So do I just need to add some module that would input two stepp CC/CV charging and cover the li-ion charging phases properly? And does it need to output 16.8V or can I boost it up?

Comment: Again a BMS is not a charger. It won't cut off. The correct charger will vary its output voltage to get the correct charging current for the CC stage then fix it for the CV stage until the current drops to a minimal level and then shut off. You don't boost its output or do anything else to it.